# Placing a finished 3D model in a photograph: matching the camera (workflow)

Tags: camera

I could really use some advice on this, I just can't seem to figure it out and may be missing something obvious.

At work I often have to make visualisations of street renovations, which need to be integrated into photographs. So I prepare the 3D model of the new street (or house) and go on location myself to take the photographs, so I also know where the real camera was positioned. So far so good, but when the time comes to put the 3D model into the photos the client has chosen things get annoying for me and I never can seem to get a good fit. Here's my workflow:

- Put the camera in the scene at the position and height I took the photo.
- Copy the right resolution, focal length and sensor size from the photograph.
- Point the camera at the same spot that's in the middle of the photograph.

As far as I know this should provide a pretty good match in theory? But in practice I need to spend a LOT of time playing around with the focal length and location, often the initital result isn't even close..

Am I missing something, or does anyone have any good tips? I tried addons like BLAM and Fspy, but they often give very weird results and don't seem suited for scenes that are already finished. I'm also not particularly experienced with the technicals behind photography. We use this camera at work (https://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/AA290/AA290A.HTM), so i guess the important thing to copy from that is the sensor size of 23.7?

Thanks for any help guys!

[image]

Comment: In theory fspy is very well suited for this kind of scenes, in streets you often have very identifiable perspective lines. Where does the workflow fail ?

Comment: @Gorgious I might be missing something in fspy but I tend to get a camera that is focussed on something that's very close to the camera. Apart from that I often already find it hard to get the width of a street to match both near the camera and towards the "horizon".